# How to make an icon slideshow with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slideshow

Hi I am building a small slideshow of icons and also want to have data inside the icons like its speed and color. I've loaded jQuery from the top of my page.

```
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="object-container">

        <div class="icon-container">
            <i class="fa fa-car" id="active"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bicycle" id="not-active"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-plane" id="not-active"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-ship" id="not-active"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" id="not-active"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle" id="not-active"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow-buttons">
            <a href="" class="right-arrow"></a>
            <a href="" class="left-arrow"></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Here is the jquery to press the right arrow button to change slide across the icons but it doesnt seem to be working?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.right-arrow').on('click', function(){
        let currentImg = $('#active');
        let nextImg = currentImg.next();

        if(currentImg.length){
            currentImg.removeAttr('#active').css('z-inex', -10)
            nextImg.attr('#active').css('z-index', 10);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend using class instead of id. Even if you are going to use id, it is not recommended to use this way. The id value must be uniq. In your case, your ID's are not uniq. And also this is better to use like this ID selector.

```
id="notActive"
```

You can just try with each function to get current div. I tried with your code but did not work, with each yes.

```
$('.fa').each(function(){
 if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
   currentImg = $(this);
  }
})
```

And bonus : You can also use current div index value, then you dont have to use prev, next. You can increase or decrease index the value one by one. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any examples with the HTML? Where would I write that function, Id assume something like rightArrow.addEventListener(onclick(function)?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `id` attribute incorrectly, as every id must be unique.

Also, setting the z-index on elements has no effect.

Finally, jQuery is not helping and can be eliminated.

Here's a more standard way to make something active/inactive, using a class named `active':

```js
// control buttons
const right = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

// handle right click
right.onclick = function() {
  const activeImg = document.querySelector('i.active');
  const nextImg = activeImg.nextElementSibling;

  if (activeImg && nextImg) {
    activeImg.classList.remove('active');
    nextImg.classList.add('active');
  }
};
```

```css
i {
  font-size: 32px;
  z-index: -10; /* this has no effect */
}

.active {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="object-container">

    <div class="icon-container">
      <i class="fa fa-car active"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-plane"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-ship"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-buttons">
      <a href="#" class="right-arrow">right-arrow</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi this doesnt seem to be working on my side. I click on the right arrow but nothing ends up happening?

Comment: @MoMiah Please post a working snippet of your code here, so we can see what's going wrong.